# amsmath matrix vs loading the array package

Tags: amsmath, arrays

Here is an interesting interaction. Consider the example below. Whenever the [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package is loaded, extra space appears on the right in the output.

Any ideas as to why?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
% without array it looks fine, with array extra space is added in the
% right of each matrix env
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \begin{array}{@{} c @{} | @{} c @{} }
        \begin{matrix}
          a_{11} & a_{12} & \hdots & a_{1n} \\
          a_{21} & a_{22} & \hdots & a_{2n} \\
          \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
          a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \hdots & a_{mn}
        \end{matrix}
        & 
        \begin{matrix}
          b_{11} & b_{12} & \cdots & b_{1n'} \\
          b_{21} & b_{22} & \cdots & b_{2n'} \\
          \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
          b_{m1} & b_{m2} & \cdots & b_{mn'}
        \end{matrix}
      \end{array}
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation*}

  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \begin{matrix}
        b_{11} & b_{12} & \cdots & b_{1n} \\
        b_{21} & b_{22} & \cdots & b_{2n} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        b_{m1} & b_{m2} & \cdots & b_{mn}
      \end{matrix}
    \end{pmatrix}  
  \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Images: First with `array`:

[image]

And without `array`:

[image]

Comment: `|` is different in `array` it extends the width of the table by that amount, in the original latex version negative space is applied either side so that the rule does not change the column spacing. looks like the lack of negative spacing has confused amsmath

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, does that explain the extra space at the `)` as well? I

Comment: possibly. one of the advantages of having a co-author on a package is that you can always blame the other author if things go wrong. (I'll look later no time now)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle trying to decide if this is a feature or a bug :-) but since I'm also partially at least responsible for the code in amsmath I can probably not hide either way

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, I've done some analysis on this and it looks like a bug that was probably introduced day one (so it is now in there for what, 20+ years? ... can't remember when I wrote that code :-).

The issue is the following: around cell content the code adds `\ignorespaces ... \unskip` to remove any unwanted space on either side. That is absolutely necessary with normal text as spaces easily creap in in something like `a & b \\` but obviously they may also be missing if somebody writes `a&b\\` and both should really produce the same output. Now in base LaTeX `tabular` and `array` are basically separate beasts and while `tabular` adds `\ignorespaces ...\unskip` this is not done with `array`. There the cells are individually surrounded by `$` signs instead.

Now with the `array` package the situation got a little more complicated as one can mark a column as math in `tabular` or as text in an  `array` simply by `>$c<$` and whenever something is "text" is should be surrounded by `\ignorespaces ...\unskip`. For that reason this is done always even though in math mode spaces are already ignored.

That is all fine unless you have a construct, such as `matrix` that explicitly adds a skip after itself (to cancel the last columnsep) as now this skip gets removed again if this `matrix`is the last object in the cell.

So the simplest way to fix this would be in `amsmath` by changing `matrix` like this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{matrix}{%
  \matrix@check\matrix\env@matrix
}{%
  \endarray \hskip -\arraycolsep\kern\z@ % hide the negative skip
}
\makeatother
```

Of course, there may be other objects that have a trailing skip, so this is not actually resolving the root cause.

A fix in `array` is much more complicated but probably doable too, please open up a latexbug report so that there is a record in the bug db.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. That was an interesting one. I'll add a bug report when I'm near a normal computer

Comment: Since amsmath is back with us now, looks like we should add the kern?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle or after all in array: we could use \ifmode\else\unskip\fi perhaps. But the precaution in amsmath is useful anyhow, so maybe both

Answer (score 12):

Simplifying the example a bit...

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
% without array it looks fine, with array extra space is added in the
% right of each matrix env
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}


  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \begin{matrix}
x
      \end{matrix}{}
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation*}


  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \begin{matrix}
x
      \end{matrix}
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Nesting `matrix` in `pmatrix` causes the space to be added if `array`  is loaded (to be investigated....)

However if you add `{}` after each `matrix` as shown in the top example then the space goes. Confirmed the space goes in your original version as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really weird one. Came upon it while editing a manuscript

Comment: @daleif I started to got debug it, got tired and pinged Frank instead, not sure he's around today, but I expect he'll comment at some point;-)